# Send data from server (php) to client (terminal)

Tags: php, bash, client-server

I am trying to make a server which will send a string to the client. Now the client is using a terminal.

I am sending this script to the server user's name.

```
curl --data "name=$name_user" http://dns1.example.com
```

1) How can I send back the user a string "Hey your name is "

2) How can I receive that string back in the user's terminal and store it in a file ?

Comment: 1. you have server and upon hit should return "Hey your name is blah" to the client?
2. And you want to store the same string "Hey your name is blah"  in a file in the client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.In the filename.php file you write like something like this -

```
<?php
  if( $_REQUEST["name"] )
  {
     echo "Hey your name is ".$_REQUEST['name'];
  }
?>
```

2.Use `curl --data "name=$name_user" http://dns1.example.com > /path/to/outputFile`

The `>` will redirect your output to a file.

Thanks!